# Position Text Relative to an Image

Tags: html, css, alignment, frontend, center

I have several images with unique captions, and I want the unique caption to show up in the center of the image being hovered over. Here is my code:

---

```css
    .photos-container img {
    
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-basis: auto;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-content: center;
    padding: 7px;
    width: 30%;
    transform: scale(1.00);
    float: left;
}

    .photos-container h2{
    color: #091253;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin: 2% 46%;
    font-size: 35px;
}

    .notes {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 30pt;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 opacity: 0;
    color: #091253;
    display: block;
}

    .photos-container img:hover + .notes {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
  <div class="photos-container">
            <h2>Photo's</h2>
            <div class="photo-1">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/43/d2/06/43d2062cf1aae38642df128288356b29.jpg">
                <div class="notes">Test #1</div>
                </a>
             </div>
            <div class="photo-1">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/43/d2/06/43d2062cf1aae38642df128288356b29.jpg">
                <div class="notes">Test #2</div>
                </a>
             </div>
            <div class="photo-1">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/43/d2/06/43d2062cf1aae38642df128288356b29.jpg">
                <div class="notes">Test #3</div>
                </a>
             </div>
           </div>
```

---

When I hover over the images the correct caption shows, but the caption won't center inside of the correct image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i corrected you css, added displays to div,and spicified the width of img-div then give it relative position  try this :

```css
.photos-container img {
    
    
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-basis: auto;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-content: center;
    padding: 7px;
    transform: scale(1.00);
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

    .photos-container h2{
    color: #091253;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin: 2% 46%;
    font-size: 35px;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

    .notes {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 30pt;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 opacity: 0;
    color: #091253;
    display:inline-block
}

    .photos-container img:hover + .notes {
    opacity: 1;
}
.photo-1{position:relative;display:inline-block;width: 32%;}
```

```html
<div class="photos-container">
            <h2>Photo's</h2>
            <div class="photo-1">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/43/d2/06/43d2062cf1aae38642df128288356b29.jpg">
                <div class="notes">Test #1</div>
                </a>
             </div>
            <div class="photo-1">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/43/d2/06/43d2062cf1aae38642df128288356b29.jpg">
                <div class="notes">Test #2</div>
                </a>
             </div>
            <div class="photo-1">
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/43/d2/06/43d2062cf1aae38642df128288356b29.jpg">
                <div class="notes">Test #3</div>
                </a>
             </div>
           </div>
```